# Global name inside a class is not defined

Tags: python, class

So I've been messing around with this all day, and I still can't get it to work

```
class pleaseWork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo=printThis(1)
        self.bar=printThis(2)
    def printThis(x):
        if x==1:
            print "foot"
        elif x==2:
            print "bar"

result=pleaseWork()

result.bar
```

It just returns

```
NameError: global name 'printThis' is not defined
```

please tell me why it's not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `printThis` is an attribute of the current object.

```
self.foo = self.printThis(1)
```

Comment: The OP will also need to give `printThis` a `self` parameter, and `result.bar` will be `None` because `printThis` doesn't return anything.

Comment: that still won't work because he forgot to add the self parameter to printThis's declaration. check my answer.

Comment: Sure, but that's a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
class pleaseWork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo=self.printThis(1)
        self.bar=self.printThis(2)
    def printThis(self, x):
        if x==1:
            print "foot"
        elif x==2:
            print "bar"

result=pleaseWork()

result.bar
```